# Codeception coverage not working with Symfony

Tags: symfony, code-coverage, codeception

I am working on a symfony project with codeception. Everything is working fine except for the code coverage. I wrote a test that executes a function. When I set a breakpoint using XDebug and run the CLI, the breakpoint is hit, but when I look at the report, it says the code wasn't hit. The test was ran though and gives the correct result

I am not using c3.php as I run my tests locally.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 */
class User extends BaseUser implements ParticipantInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}
```

This is the test

```
public function testGetId()
{
    $user = new User();
    $this->invokeProperty($user, 'id', 1);
    $this->assertEquals(1, $user->getId());
}
```

[image]

[image]

Codeception.yml

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: ''
            user: ''
            password: ''
            dump: tests/_data/dump.sql
include:
    - src/*Bundle
coverage:
    enabled: true
    remote: false
    include:
        - src/*
    exclude:
        - src/AppBundle/Resources/*
        - src/AppBundle/Tests/*
```

My Suite.

```
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Symfony2:
            app_path: '../../app'
            var_path: '../../app'
        - Doctrine2:
            depends: Symfony2
        - AppBundle\Helper\Functional
```

Comment: Are you using PHP or HHVM?

Comment: Please add configuration of this suite. Do you use Symfony2, PhpBrowser or WebDriver module?

Comment: I am using Symfony 2

Comment: Do you have any ID ?

Comment: No, I just want to point out that Codeception does not do code coverage itself, but uses https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage to do it. It is a more appropriate place to report this issue.